# Vue.js 3 : Accessing a dynamically created component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a vue.js 3 application that needs to dynamically create components and access them.

The proper way to dynamically create them and injected them in the DOM seems to be th wrap them in an app using `createApp`, and this part works, when I call `test()` a new copy of the components appears at the bottom of the DOM.

Now I need to be able to get a reference to that component son I can call public (exposed) methods on it.

In my (actual) code below, what would allow me to get a reference to my component ?

```
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import ConfirmModal from '@/views/components/ui/confirm-modal.vue';

function test()
{
    let componentApp = createApp({
        setup() {
            return () => h(ConfirmModal, { title: "Fuck yeah!", type: "primary" });
        }
    });

    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.setAttribute('id', 'confirm-modal-0');
    componentApp.mount(wrapper);
    document.body.appendChild(wrapper);

    let _confirmModal: ConfirmModal = ???????????????????

    _confirmModal.show();
}
```

EDIT : Here's my use-case: I have a helper function in a service which is used to confirm actions (like deletes) using a Modal dialog. This helper/service is pure TS, not a Vue component, but needs to instanciate the modal (which is a vue component), have it injected in the DOM and have its public methods callable (by my helper/service).

Right now, the only thing that works is to have a sungle copy of the modal component in my root layout and have to root layout foward the ref to my service, which can then use the component. But this isn't great because I need multiple instances of the dialog, and isn't good SOC to have to root layout handle a modal dialog.

Comment: I find this module quite useful for creating, mounting and then using components dynamically: https://github.com/pearofducks/mount-vue-component. The `mount` function returns all you need.

Comment: Let talk about what is the goal when you create a dynamic component like that. The way you use the `createApp` function, Vue will create a new Vue instance and it will not share the same store and router with your Vue application.

Comment: @Duannx It is true, a separate Vue app is way overkill, but the only way I could mount a component. I added my use-case at the ottom of my question, if that clarifies my itent.

Comment: Your use case is a very good candidate for event sourcing. You should put your Modal component inside App.vue and then subscribe for as many events as you need (e.g. Show, Hide, etc.) Then anywhere in your app, whenever you need a simple confirmation dialog - you simply emit the needed event on your event bus. There is no need to make your life more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @IVOGELOV But if I place a single modal component in my app root and have it listen to events, that means only one modal can be shown at a time.

Comment: @AlexandreDanault Why not put one Modal component in every place you want to use it? It's a much easier and more natural way. I don't see any benefit when you try to dynamic add a modal by javascript in this use case.

Comment: As @AlexandreDanault suggested - if you need several modals open at the same time then it will be simpler and easier to just import them in every other component when you need a modal.

Comment: @Duannx In the end I went this way (component on each page where it is needed), it is indeed simpler, even is more verbose. Thanks !